# Не выводится в DataGrid строки результата

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Помогите пожалуйста! В DataGrid не выводятся результат запроса, хотя сами столбцы появляются. Вот код:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using TERAPIST.TERAPISTbdModel;

namespace TERAPIST
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для TestResult.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class TestResult : Window
    {
        //public string User = LogUser.Connectuser;
        TerapistContext db;
        public TestResult()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = D:\КУРСОВОЙ ПРОЕКТ\TERAPIST\TERAPIST\Terapistbd.mdf; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30");
            //string sqlSel = " SELECT User, Date FROM Test ORDER BY Date WHERE User=@User";
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM Test WHERE User='{LogUser.Connectuser}'", sqlCon);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Test");

            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView; 
        }
       }
      }
```

и вот само окошко

```
<Window x:Class="TERAPIST.TestResult"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TERAPIST"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Icon="C:\Users\Badass Nick\source\repos\TERAPIST\packages\Icons\520638.jpeg"
               Title="Результаты тестирования" Background="Aquamarine" Height="300" Width="450">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="dataGrid1"  />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Возможно ли это из-за того, что имя пользователя с пробелом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Скорее всего, необходимо User заключить в квадратные скобки [ ] таким образом: 
   WHERE [User]=....  так как это зарезервированное слово в SQL Server.
2. Выполни запрос напрямую в базе и посмотри, возвращаются ли данные.
3. Откуда у тебя берётся LogUser.Connectuser? Он точно в интерполируемую строку попадает?

Comment: LogUser возвращает строку с логином пользователя, при этом является public static-ом